# Css how to automatically make the left bar the same height as the right bar

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and I have this situation: in my website I have a background image (which takes up the whole page)and a frame div (in which I insert the contents of my website); the frame has a top-banner div and, under this one, the frame is divided into a left and a right bar. My question is how to make the left bar the same lenght (in height) as the right bar, because it happens that the right bar gets longer, but the left bar remains of the fixed length.

```css
body{
   background-image: url("../img/cd.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 2100px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}

#frame{
   background-color: white;
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

#left_bar{
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #b3d1ff;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 10px;
    min-height: 1100px; 
}

#right_bar{
    float: right;
    width: 78%;
}
```

```html
<body>           
  <div id="frame">
  <div id="top_banner"></div>
  <div id="left_bar"></div>
  <div id="right_bar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what "length" are you referring to here? height or width?

Comment: this snippet is showing one slice of blue.where is the other slice?i want to make sandwich.

Comment: I refer to height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `left_bar` and `right_bar` into 1 `div` and make it `display: flex`

```html
<div style="display: flex">
  <div id="left_bar"></div>
  <div id="right_bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a flexbox here. [Here is a good guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you are interested.

For example:

```css
body{
   background-image: url("../img/cd.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 2100px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background-attachment: fixed;
}

#frame{
   background-color: white;
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
}

#top_banner {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#left_bar{
    width: 22%;
    background-color: #b3d1ff;
    border-radius: 0 0 0px 10px;
    min-height: 1100px; 
}

#right_bar{ 
    background-color: #ff0000;
    width: 78%;
}
```

```html
<body>           
  <div id="frame">
  <div id="top_banner"></div>
  <div id="left_bar"></div>
  <div id="right_bar"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: What about it doesn't work? In your question and comments above, you state you want the heights of left and right bars to stay equal, this does just that...

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while coping it, it is correct!